# Zend_Validate_File_IsImage can't detect PNG

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using Zend_Validate_File_IsImage on a file upload, just using this code, essentially:

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http;
$adapter->addValidator('IsImage', false);
if (!$adapter->receive()) { /* error... */ }
```

I took the image found here (just happened to have that page open):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/coding-horror-official-logo-small.png

saved it as horror.png and tried to uploaded it, and it works fine on my dev machine (Mac OSX), but it fails on the production server (Ubuntu) saying:

```
File 'horror.png' is no image, 'text/plain' detected
```

Comment: whats the version of your PHP on dev & production ? Do you have pecl fileinfo installed ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  My dev machine is 5.3 and production is 5.2.  I always forget about that.  I'm on vacation and I just talked to my boss and they're installing fileinfo today.  Thanks for the response!